# DetailView and templates

Tags: django, django-generic-views

**Django 1.9.7**

Could you help me with three questions about DetailView:

1. Why DetailView doesn't put form into the context whereas CreateView does?
   I mean it is very cumbersome to write a template where every field is shown separately like object.headline or object.content. In case of CreateView we just place {{ form.as_p }} into the template. Much more convenient. So, there must be some logic behind the scene that I can't feel because of lack of experience.
2. Is there a third party applications with ready to use template tags for DetailView? Or something else to automate this selection of fields to be displayed in the template.
3. Or should I just put a form myself in get_context_data?

Comment: Why would DetailView, which is all about displaying, do anything with a form at all?

Comment: Pardon. Could you have a look at my comment to the first answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DetailView` is not intended for editing. Use `UpdateView` for that purpose.

If you want to display each field in the same format loop over them, you must pass your field names in the context as a list and then loop over this list:

```
{% for field_name in field_names %}
  <tr>
    <th>{% get_field_label object field_name %}</th>
    <td>{% get_field_value object field_name %}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

And create custom template tags:

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_field_label(obj, name):
    return obj._meta.get_field(name).verbose_name

@register.simple_tag
def get_field_value(obj, name):
    return getattr(obj, value)
```

Comment: Pardon for the form. Well, I don't need any update. I just don't want to manually pick all fields from the object. Is there a method for that?